# Find a phrase in defined list with a file

Tags: python

I have a list name `my= ['cbs is down','abnormal']`
and I have opened a file in read mode

Now I want to search any of the string available in list that exist in that file and perform the if action

```
fopen  =  open("test.txt","r")
my =['cbs is down', 'abnormal']
for line in fopen:
    if my in line:
            print ("down")
```

and when I execute it, I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/fileread.py", line 4, in <module>
    if my in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work things out:

```
if any(i in line for i in my):
    ...
```

Basically you are going through `my` and checking whether `any` of its elements is present in line.

Answer (score 1):

```
fopen  =  open("test.txt","r")
my =['cbs is down', 'abnormal']
for line in fopen:
    for x in my:
        if x in line:
            print ("down")
```

Sample input

```
Some text cbs is down
Yes, abnormal
not in my list
cbs is down
```

Output

```
down
down
down
```

Comment: This prints `down` once for _each_ match in `my`. Might or might not be what OP wants, but I think it's not. On the plus side, you know _which_ `x` was found, and you can still `break` after the first one.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>The reason for your error:</sub>

The `in` operator as used in:

```
if my in line: ...
   ^       ^
   |_ left | hand side 
           |
           |_ right hand side
```

for a string operand on the right side (i.e. `line`) requires a corresponding string operand on the left hand side. This operand consistency check is implemented by the `str.__contains__` method, where the call to `__contains__` is made from the string on the right hand side (see [cpython implemenetation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L11201)). Same as:

```
if line.__contains__(my): ...
```

You're however passing a list, `my`, instead of a string.

An easy way to resolve this is by check that **any**  of the items in the list are contained in the current line using the builtin [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)  function:

```
for line in fopen:
    if any(item in line for item in my):
       ...
```

Or since you have just two items use the [**`or`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) operator (pun unintended) which *short-circuits* in the same way as `any`:

```
for line in fopen:
    if 'cbs is down' in line or 'abnormal' in line:
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `join` the terms in `my` to a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like `\b(cbs is down|abnormal)\b` and use `re.findall` or `re.search` to find the terms. This way, you can also enclose the pattern in word-boundaries `\b...\b` so it does not match parts of longer words, and you also see *which* term was matched, and where.

```
>>> import re
>>> my = ['cbs is down', 'abnormal']
>>> line = "notacbs is downright abnormal"
>>> p = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, my)) + r")\b")
>>> p.findall(line)
['abnormal']
>>> p.search(line).span()
(21, 29)
```